# Запуск плагина под-под-модуля в maven

Tags: maven

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу осуществить запуск плагина для подподмодуля родительского модуля. При такой структуре:

```
backend
- backend-core
  - backend-core-jar
  - backend-core-war
- backend-dashboard
```

вызов `mvn jetty:run -pl backend-core-war` приводит к ошибке (модуль не найден -  `Could not find the selected project in the reactor: backend-core-war`), в то время как выполнение той же команды в `backend-core` будет успешным - подозреваю, мне нужно указать полную иерархическую ветвь до модуля. Как правильно указать конкретный дважды подмодуль для запуска плагина в контексте этого подмодуля?